# Tutorial – BDD and Dependency Injection in .Net (4)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

Please help me in removing Mock error in bold letters.

> Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Mock' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\MOB140003208\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissorsTest\Tests\GameTest.cs   65  34  RockPaperScissorsTest
>
> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'Mock' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\MOB140003208\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissorsTest\Tests\GameTest.cs   77  34  RockPaperScissorsTest
>
> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'Mock' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\MOB140003208\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissorsTest\Tests\GameTest.cs   89  34  RockPaperScissorsTest

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using RockPaperScissors;

namespace RockPaperScissorsTest.Tests
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for GameTest
/// </summary>
[TestClass]
public class GameTest
{
    public GameTest()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    /// <summary>
    ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
    ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
    ///</summary>
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }

    #region Additional test attributes
    //
    // You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
    //
    // Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
    // [ClassInitialize()]
    // public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext) { }
    //
    // Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
    // [ClassCleanup()]
    // public static void MyClassCleanup() { }
    //
    // Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
    // [TestInitialize()]
    // public void MyTestInitialize() { }
    //
    // Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
    // [TestCleanup()]
    // public void MyTestCleanup() { }
    //
    #endregion

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReturnsCorrectMessageIfPlayerWins()
    {
        var engineMock = new **Mock**();
        engineMock.Setup(de => de.Result(Move.Rock, Move.Paper)).Returns(GameResult.PlayerWins);
        var game = new Game(engineMock.Object);
        game.PlayerMove = "Paper";
        var result = game.Result();
        engineMock.VerifyAll();
        Assert.AreEqual("Player Wins!", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReturnsCorrectMessageIfComputerWins()
    {
        var engineMock = new **Mock**();
        engineMock.Setup(de => de.Result(Move.Rock, Move.Scissors)).Returns(GameResult.ComputerWins);
        var game = new Game(engineMock.Object);
        game.PlayerMove = "Scissors";
        var result = game.Result();
        engineMock.VerifyAll();
        Assert.AreEqual("Computer Wins!", result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void ThrowsErrorIfPlayerMoveIsNotSet()
    {
        var engineMock = new **Mock**();
        var game = new Game(engineMock.Object);
        game.Result();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: well your error messages tells the tale: you are trying to use **Moq** (I guess) but did not fully quallify it's name - so add the `using` at the top of the file (or fully quallify it) and make sure you have the references to Moq set (I guess you'll want to use Nuget for that)

Answer (score 1):

> are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Yes you are. You need to add a reference to the assembly containing the `Mock` type. You also need to add a `using` statement to be able to use the `Mock` type without having to add the namespace in front.

So make sure that you have a reference to the `Moq` assembly (preferably by using NuGet) and make sure that you add `using Moq;` at the top of your source code.